# Soccer league table standings with SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Perhaps a familiar table for many people. A soccer league table. 
But, in this list there is one mistake, rank 4 and 5, are totally equal, so these teams should not be ranked 4 and 5, but 4 and 4, and then the ranking should continue with 6.

```
Ranking | Team | Points | Goals difference | Goals scored | Goals against
1         A      3        4                  4              0
2         B      3        3                  3              0 
3         C      3        1                  2              1
4         D      3        1                  1              0
5         E      3        1                  1              0
6         F      1        0                  2              2 
7         G      1        0                  0              0
```

I have been trying to improve the MS SQL query that produces this table, by using a Common Table Expression and SELECT ROW_Number, but that never gives me the right result. Does anyone have a better idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this easy by using the [RANK()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176102.aspx) function.

```
declare @table as table
(
    Team varchar(1),
    Points int,
    GoalsScored int,
    GoalsAgainst int
)

insert into @table values ('A', 3, 4, 0),
                          ('B', 3, 3, 0),
                          ('C', 3, 2, 1),
                          ('D', 3, 1, 0),
                          ('E', 3, 1, 0),
                          ('F', 1, 2, 2),
                          ('G', 1, 0, 0)

select RANK() OVER (ORDER BY points desc, GoalsScored - GoalsAgainst desc, GoalsScored desc) AS Rank   
      ,team
      ,points
      ,GoalsScored - GoalsAgainst as GoalsDifference
      ,GoalsScored
      ,GoalsAgainst
from @table
order by rank
```

Comment: Indeed, that was it. I totally forgot about the RANK function! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution. I'm not sure specifically how you are ranking so I've ranked based on Points DESC, Goals Diff DESC, Goals Scored DESC and Goals Against ASC.

```
;WITH

src AS (
    SELECT Team, Points, GoalsDiff, GoalsScor, GoalsAga
    FROM dbo.[stats]
)

,src2 AS (
    SELECT Points, GoalsDiff, GoalsScor, GoalsAga
    FROM src
    GROUP BY Points, GoalsDiff, GoalsScor, GoalsAga
)

,src3 AS (
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Points DESC, GoalsDiff DESC, GoalsScor DESC, GoalsAga) AS Ranking
    ,Points, GoalsDiff, GoalsScor, GoalsAga
    FROM src2
)

SELECT src3.Ranking, src.Team, src.Points, src.GoalsDiff, src.GoalsScor, src.GoalsAga
FROM src
    INNER JOIN src3
        ON src.Points = src3.Points
        AND src.GoalsDiff = src3.GoalsDiff
        AND src.GoalsScor = src3.GoalsScor
        AND src.GoalsAga = src3.GoalsAga
```

The basic approach I used is to select just the stats themselves then group them all. Once grouped then you can rank them and then join the grouped stats with ranking back to the original data to get your rank numbers against the teams. One way to think of it is that you are ranking the stats not the teams.

Hope this helps.